# Xacro problems in Indigo

Tags: ros-indigo, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently installed Indigo on a fresh 14.04 install after working in Hydro for a while, and xacro code that used to work no longer works. When I simply try to run xacro.py I get errors complaining about kobuki_description, which the internet doesn't seem to know much about. Any help?

```
’$:’rosrun xacro xacro.py neato.urdf.xacro > model.urdf
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
        xacro.main()
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 653, in main
        process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(args[0]))
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 245, in process_includes
        filename_spec = eval_text(elt.getAttribute('filename'), {})
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 484, in eval_text
        results.append(handle_extension(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 472, in handle_extension
        return eval_extension("$(%s)" % s)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 66, in eval_extension
        return substitution_args.resolve_args(str, context=substitution_args_context, resolve_anon=False)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 299, in resolve_args
        resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 312, in _resolve_args
        resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
      File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 145, in _find
        pkg_path = rp.get_path(args[0])
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 190, in get_path
        raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
    
    rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: kobuki_description
    ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
    ROS path [1]=/home/eon-alone/catkin_ws/src
    ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
    ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193327/xacro-problems-in-indigo/) by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The  problem is that kobuki_description apparently is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH of your indigo-workspace. You'd get the exact same error if this was the case in hydro, so this isn't really indigo-specific.

Running

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-kobuki
```

should fix the problem. Also see this related Q/A: http://answers.ros.org/question/190137/problem-of-installing-kobuki-in-turtlebot-installation-indigo/

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on 2014-09-23**:
That worked, thanks! It must not be installed as part of ros-indigo-desktop-full. Now I need to try and install the turtlebot stuff from source, because debs aren't available yet.